# How to return days between two calendar dates (From, To) except Saturday & Sunday using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

For example if i set From date as 1 Oct 2016 and To date as 19 Oct 2016, i must get the dates without Saturday & Sunday

The output should be as below image 
[image]

Also is there any way to not display National Holidays in the output?

Comment: that will be very easy. just loop through all the days one by one and check whether thats a weekend or not, else increment the counter. Just try this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution as per comment of **@vijayP** . Increment day counting counter `numDays` if day is **not** Saturday (6) or Sunday(0).

```
var startDate =  new Date('1 Oct 2016');
var endDate =  new Date('19 Oct 2016');
var numDays = 0;

while(startDate < endDate)
{
 startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

 if(startDate.getDay() == 0 || startDate.getDay() == 6)
   continue;

 numDays = numDays +1;
}

alert(numDays);
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yav2maun/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWorkingDates(startDate, endDate) {
    var curDate = startDate;
    var days = [];
    while (curDate <= endDate) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if(!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0)))
           days.push(new Date(curDate));
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
}
```

If you want to exclude National Holidays, you need to have an array of dates for these. Need to check your date with holiday array before pushing to days array.

```
function getWorkingDates(startDate, endDate) {
        var curDate = startDate;
        var days = [];
        while (curDate <= endDate) {
            var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
            if(!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0))){
            if($.inArray(curDate, holidayArray) != -1)
              days.push(new Date(curDate));
            }

            curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return days;
    }
```